# How do I mute the sound when opening a folder in the home screen?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, audio, home-screen-folders

I have a Galaxy Note 2, running Android 4.1.2.

Everytime I open or close a folder on the home screen, I hear a click sound. How can I mute this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, but see if you can find something similar to this: `Settings > My device > Sound > Touch sounds`.

Comment: @Elad Benda If you found the correct procedure, please share it here so I can update the answer. :)

Comment: no, it's all turned off. That's the weird thing - I hear the `tick` sound only when I open or close apps folder. Not when tapping or anything else.